# Office JS API - settings.getItem is not a function

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to retrieve a setting within a document which I have previously saved within the same session, however i'm getting `settings.getItem is not a function`.

I'm attempting to do this via an Word Online session within Chrome, and have been referring to the documentation [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/word/settingcollection.md#getitemornullobjectkey-string), and have also seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150904/issue-with-office-context-document-settings-get/45152781#45152781) (but I don't think it fits my specific problem)

As mentioned, saving the setting works fine and when I download the file I can see the setting has been saved.

I'm using react + redux for this, so the snippet below is from the redux action creator:

```
export function getSetting() {
    //this function tries to find a setting within the document
    return function(dispatch, getState) {
        window.Word.run(
            function(context) {
                let settings = Office.context.document.settings
                var thisSetting 
                try {
                    console.log('attempting to find existing setting for ' + constants.ORG_ID)
                    thisSetting = settings.getItem(constants.ORG_ID)
                    console.log('got ' + thisSetting.value)
                    context.load(thisSetting)
                } catch (error) {
                    thisSetting = null
                    console.log('couldn\'t find setting)
                    console.log(error.message)
                }                    
                return context.sync()
                .then(
                    function() {
                        if (thisSetting) {
                            dispatch(requestSetThisSetting (thisSetting.value))
                            console.log('got setting ' + thisSetting.value)
                        }
                    }
                )             
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**Any ideas on how I can successfully retrieve settings?**

**Updated code based on answer (below)**

I've updated this post with working code based on the answer provided by Rick and Juan (thanks guys!)

```
export function getSetting() {
    //this function tries to find a setting within the document
    return function(dispatch, getState) {
        let currentSetting = Office.context.document.settings.get(constants.ORG_ID)
        console.log('current setting is ' + currentSetting)
        if (currentSetting) dispatch(requestSetSetting(currentSetting))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are kind of mixing the Shared API Office.context.document.settings inside a Word.run from the Word-specific APIs. Take a look at the special Word wrapper API (from ver. 1.4 of the Word-specific APIs): [SettingsCollection](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.4_OpenSpec/reference/word/settingcollection.md). This is the context.document.settings object, but the "context" here is the Word.RequestContext object that is passed to Word.run, not the Office.context object. Your code gets a settings object using the Shared API **Office**.context.document.settings, but then it calls the getItem and load methods from the **Word**.RequestContext.document.settings.

Under the hood, it is the same settings OOXML in the file, but accessing it through the two different APIs might be problematic.

**UPDATE**: In light of Juan Balmori's comment, here's some info on reading a setting using the Shared API: [Getting the value of a setting](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings#getting-the-value-of-a-setting). And see here for info on the distinction between the Common and host-specific APIs: [JavaScript API for Office](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office).

Comment: 1.4 is on Preview, so i would recommend you to use the shared API to retrieve the settings.