# Office document settings

Tags: excel, office-js

I am currently storing a key value pair in `Office.context.documents.settings` using the following function:

```
Office.context.document.settings.set(name, value);
```

Once the key-value pair is stored , I am relaunching the add-in and trying to fetch the value using the following function -

```
Office.context.document.settings.get(name);
```

But the function is returning `null` instead of the proper value. Does the value stored in document settings persist across multiple sessions of an application or does it get refreshed once we close the application?

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't have a lot of detail but there are two common errors when working with settings:

**Failure to Load Settings**

Prior to reading a given setting, you need to populate the `settings` object. This is done using [`refreshAsync()`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings.refreshasync):

```js
Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync(function(){
    Office.context.document.settings.get(name);
});
```

**Side-loaded Add-ins**

When you side-load an add-in, Office generates a random ID and assigns it to your add-in. If you remove and re-side-load the add-in, it will generate a new ID. You'll also get two distinct IDs if you side-load the same add-on on two different machines.

This will affect how `settings` function since settings are keyed by the Add-in ID when they are stored or recalled from a document. For details on how this works (and how to get around it), see [Issue with Office.context.document.settings.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150904/issue-with-office-context-document-settings-get/45152781#45152781).

Comment: I think my issue is related to side-loading add-in . Once i am reloading the add-in, i am unable to fetch the value from Office document settings.

Comment: Instructions for how to handle this is in the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

The setting isn't being saved because you did not call `saveAsync`. The `set` method only saves the setting in memory, not to the file. To save to the file you must first call `set`, then call:

```
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync(callback);
```

Then when you reload the add-in you will be able to retrieve the settings with `get`. Here's the documentation page for the `saveAsync` method: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings.saveasync

-Michael, PM for add-ins