# Using project application settings in Excel Web Add-in development Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

We are currently trying to developing an Excel web Add-in ([Excel Office add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/)).

While development, we came across a requirement to preserve current user's details in the add-in (from a third-party login inside add-in) like userID, userName, etc.

**GOAL:**

The goal is to save excel add-in user-related settings most preferably into the application's settings.
[image: Project -> Properties -> Settings]

**WHAT WE TRIED:**

Tried [Office.Settings interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.settings): We created and saved a sample setting(using settings.set() and saveAsync() methods respectively).
According to the saveAsync() [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.settings?view=excel-js-preview#saveAsync_options__callback_):

> Any settings previously saved by an add-in are loaded when it is initialized, so during the lifetime of the session you can just use the set and get methods to work with the in-memory copy of the settings property bag. When you want to persist the settings so that they are available the next time the add-in is used, use the saveAsync method.

But in our case, after saving the settings (using saveAsync) and reading the settings (after excel restart) with refreshAsync(), we are still getting null value.

```
Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync(function(){
Office.context.document.settings.get('mySetting');});
```

After crawling more on the internet, we got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47755782/office-document-settings) but it didn't help much to persist the settings.

Can anybody guide us, how we can save Excel web add-in settings somewhere?