# Office.context.document.settings.get Not Working Across Multiple Platforms For The Same Word Add-In

Tags: office-js

In a published Word add-in, I am using the `Office.context.document.settings.get` method to retrieve data previously saved by the `Office.context.document.settings.set` and its corresponding `Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync` methods from `Word Javascript API Version 1.1`. When saving data to the Word document (specifically the `webextension.xml` file) on the same user setup (Word Version, Platform, OS, etc), the correct data can be retrieved without issue. However, when opening the same Word document and launching the same published add-in on another machine (for example, a different Word Version), the `Office.context.document.settings.get` method returns `null`, and a second webextension file is created (`webextension2.xml`).

I understand that when an add-in is loaded, Office uses the `id` from the manifest file as the key to make sure the data is not overwritten by another add-in, as described nicely in this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150904/issue-with-office-context-document-settings-get?noredirect=1&lq=1). In my previously mentioned issue, the `id`, `version`, `store` and `storeType` attribute of the `we:reference` element in the `webextension.xml` file contain the correct data from our add-in's Manifest file. Somehow, it appears Office does not recognize this data as from the same add-in.

Any other ideas as to why the `Office.context.document.settings.get` is returning null in this case?

Sample xml
`webextension1.xml`: sample xml (can no longer be identified as belonging to our application)

```
<we:reference id="id1234" version="3.0.0.0" store="en-US" storeType="OMEX"/>
<we:alternateReferences>
    <we:reference id="id1234" version="3.0.0.0" store="id1234" storeType="OMEX"/>
</we:alternateReferences>
```

`webextension2.xml`: sample xml (can be identified as created by our application)

```
<we:reference id="id1234" version="3.0.0.0" store="en-001" storeType="OMEX"/>
<we:alternateReferences>
    <we:reference id="id1234" version="3.0.0.0" store="en-001" storeType="OMEX"/>
</we:alternateReferences>
```

**Additional Context**

- I only noticed this problem over the last week (the add-in has been published for ~3 years), so it may be attributed to a recent Word or office-js release.
- I also posted this issue in the [office-js repository](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1585).

Comment: A similar issue for Excel can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65720404/office-settings-not-retrievable-in-excel-online-when-created-and-set-in-excel-de). An important note is that this issue here and the one I linked to occurs when the add-in is installed via the Microsoft App Store, not sideloading during development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to mention to anyone else viewing this in the future...the Microsoft team fixed this [bug with a recent release](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1585).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Word is lacking an API to store key-value pairs per-user across devices and across documents. Outlook has an API called Office.RoamingSettings which does exactly this, but it is not available in Word.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings

I've also seen more issues around this recently. I use the `localStorage` api to share key-value pairs across documents (but this still does not work across devices).

Someone from Microsoft might be able to clarify this better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Interesting to hear that you are also experiencing more issues around your integration recently.