# Office.Settings not retrievable in Excel Online when created and set in Excel Desktop

Tags: excel, settings, office-js, office-addins, scriptlab

According to the API docs, the [Office.Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.settings?view=excel-js-preview) objects are saved per add-in and per document. That is, they are available only to the add-in that created them, and only from the document in which they are saved.

I'm a bit confused regarding the Office.Settings interface. I've created a gist in the ScriptLab Add-in where I set 2 setting objects (queries and queryIDs) and then retrieve them (log them to console).

Gist: https://gist.github.com/VivianVenter/e5489628384f96f2d3bf9a50aace8728

If I run this gist on Excel Desktop, then I can create the settings and retrieve them successfully. If I save this workbook and open it in Excel Online and run the gist again then I cannot retrieve the settings, it returns null for both settings object.

According to my knowledge the ScriptLab Add-in is the same for the Desktop and Online version, am I missing something, or is it the intention of OfficeJS to not make the settings available/visible in the Online version if it was created and set in the Desktop version?

**Settings desktop found:**
[The settings objects was found in Excel Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDaPV.png)

**Settings online null:**
[The settings objects was NOT found in Excel Online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcLvM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a [bug in office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1585) which has now been fixed upstream.

Answer (score 1):

Office add-in's setting is stored based on the add-in's id.
And once it is installed by side-loading, a new id is allocated to the add-in every time.
This means you can't sync settings on multiple platforms while developing.

Once you submitted the add-in to the AppSource, a static id from AppSource is allocated to the add-in and it is used while installing the add-in from AppSource.

So, you should submit the add-in to AppSource to test/implement this feature.

Comment: I completely understand your reasoning above, however, ScriptLab is an app in the store so it should have a static id from my understanding and it is not sideloaded during the tests mentioned above